# Illegal string offset in array_map

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Try use function array_map

```
 array_map(function ($items) {
                    return $items[$this->relatedKey];
                }, $this->parseIds($ids))
```

$`ids` is array of item => value:

```
 $ids = array:1 [
      "parent_id" => "15"
    ]
```

Key what need to find:

```
$this->relatedKey = "parent_id"
```

And get error:

```
Illegal string offset 'parent_id'
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: if you do `array_map` on an array, you get the values in the var `$items`, so `"15"` in your case, and `"15"` has no index "parent_id", it's not an array. It seems you use `array_map` for the wrong purpose, it is used to apply a function to all items in an array and return resulting new array with affected values. To acces a specific key in PHP, simply use `$ids[$this->relatedKey]`

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example taken from the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
<?php
function cube($n)
{
    return($n * $n * $n);
}

$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$b = array_map("cube", $a);
print_r($b);
```

It will return an array with 1, 8, 27, etc ...

The name `$items` you used for the parameter is misleading, because the argument will be each single `$item` of your array, and `array_map()` is supposed to transform it somehow.

I'm not sure about what you want to do, but apparently you won't need `array_map()` for your purpose.